# Using comma in fronting with inversion (for “there”)

Tags: grammar, commas

Be the following sentence:

- *Opposite to the window (**there**) was the last fleeting flower, which the shy lass hastily took.*

I would like to know if, in case I use “there”, I should place a comma after “window”.

Grateful for your help.

Comment: "Opposite to the window" sounds really funny in  your sentence. But, yes, a comma there would be good. Opposite the car park stood the hamburger billboard.

Comment: I suspected my word choice was not the best—previously, I wrote: "In front of"—but I posted the sentence in this way, so a native speaker’s ear could better detect the correct register than me. Thanks.

Comment: @Lambie Are you suggesting that in the sentence "Opposite the car park, _there_ stood the hamburger billboard" **opposite the car park** is parenthetical as it would be in "There stood, opposite the car park, the hamburger billboard"? I'm not sure that that is necessarily the case and I can see no other reason for the comma. Personally I think that the **opposite the X** phrases are simply adverbial phrases modifying 'was' in the OP and 'stood' in  your example and, therefore, no comma is needed.

Comment: @BoldBen I was using "opposite the car park" in a manner that makes sense. "opposite the window was the last fleeting flower" does not make sense to me to due the incongruity of the two things. It makes more SENSE for a billboard to be located opposite a car park, but not for a "fleeting flower** to be **opposite a window**. If he uses, "there", a comma would be needed....

Comment: @Lambie I do prefer "in front of" which Roberto says he chose first. For me "opposite" just confused me, it didn't help me to 'detect the correct register' at all.